# The spirit helps us "in" our weakness?

Tags: word-usage

I am reading some quotes in the Bible to find some wisdom saying on "blaming others" :)
But I came across this long quotes and have some questions.

> But if we hope for what we do not see, we wait for it with patience. Likewise the Spirit helps us **in our weakness**. For we do not know what to pray for as we ought, but the Spirit himself intercedes for us with groanings too deep for words. And he who searches hearts knows what is the mind of the Spirit, because the Spirit intercedes for the saints according to the will of God. And we know that for those who love God all things work together for good, for those who are called according to his purpose. For those whom he foreknew he also predestined to be conformed to the image of his Son, in order that he might be the firstborn among many brothers.
>
> 1 "the Spirit helps us in our weakness"

-> I am not sure what the word "in" means in this context. 
So I looked up in the dictionary and found possible candidates for this but still not sure.
Does it mean:
1. when we "experience" weakness
2. the Spirit helps us fix our weakness itself?
3. or the Spirit helps us fix ourselves who has this weakness?

> 2 And we know that for those who love God all things work together for good, for those who are called according to his purpose.
>
> "for those who are called according to his purpose."
>   Is this sentence connected to "all things work together for good"? 
>   Like in "for those who are called according to his purpose, all things work together for good."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer addresses the straightforward grammatical (not theological or interpretive) aspect of the first quotation. *In our weakness* refers to *our state of weakness*. The Spirit helps us *in our state of weakness* or *while we are weak*. Anything else goes beyond English Language and Usage and belongs on [SE: Bible Hermeneutics](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/). I have not answered your second question, because you should ask one question per post.

Oxford Living Dictionaries ([link](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/in))

definition 5 for *in*:

> often followed by a noun without a determiner) expressing a state or condition.
>   ‘to be in love’
>   Other given examples include:
>   *in good health*
>   *in my twenties*

Comment: Thank you so much for your help and reminding me of the guideline:)